# How to get the file object from a (SvelteKit) POST action? (TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'byteLength'))

Tags: javascript, post, input, firebase-storage, sveltekit

Right now, to get the file from a file input in a `<form>`, I am preventing the default acting when submitting and call `const file = event.target[0].files[0];`. From here I can use the file to upload it to Firebase for example, no problem.

My problem is I actually want to move my component to a route with a `+page.server.ts` to handle the form action, so to get the value from the POSTed form, I have this:

+page.svelte:

```html
<form method="POST" action="?/uploadPDF" use:enhance enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="formFile" class="form-label">Upload new file</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="file" accept=".pdf" id="formFile" name="path" />

    <div class="form-input">
        <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="password" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-3">Upload</button>
</form>
```

+page.server.ts:

```js
export const actions = {
  uploadPDF: async ({ cookies, request }) => {
    const data = await request.formData();
    const file = data.get('path');

    console.log(file);
 
    return { success: true };
  },
} satisfies Actions;
```

But the log is always empty...

After some looking around I eventually found that `const file` could either be a File or a string, so to continue working on it I should check its instance like this:

+page.server.ts:

```js
export const actions = {
  uploadPDF: async ({ cookies, request }) => {
    const data = await request.formData();
    const file = data.get('path');

    if(file instance File) {
      console.log(file);
    }
 
    return { success: true };
  },
} satisfies Actions;
```

This way at least it prints an object. But when I hand it over to Firestore's `uploadBytes()` it still does not work (**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'byteLength')**) - other than when using `on:submit()` and `const file = event.target[0].files[0];` ....

```js
const uploadRef = ref(storage, `Vereinsblatt/soli_info_${yearFrom}_${seasonFrom}.pdf`);
await uploadBytes(uploadRef, file)
```

So how can I properly get the file object here - or create one?

(I' ve also tried to create one with `new File([file],"myFile.pdf")` or `new Blob([path])` but it was not possible neither.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file instance provided by SvelteKit might be incompatible.

You could try reading the contents to a byte array instead. This usually can be done by first using the [`arrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer) method of the file and then constructing a `Uint8Array` from the result.

```js
const bytes = new Uint8Array(await file.arrayBuffer()));
await uploadBytes(uploadRef, bytes);
```